# FlatList disable left swipe gesture

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I use the horizontal `FlatList` in my application to render the data.

The goal is to `disable` the back scroll to the previous tile and `allow` scrolling to the next tile when the user presses on the button. There's a prop `gesturesEnabled`, but it possible to lock only one swipe direction?

I've tried `react-native-swipe-gestures`, but I am stuck with this issue https://github.com/glepur/react-native-swipe-gestures/issues/13 and it's not working as expected.

Is there any way to solve this problem with a `FlatList`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can do this through the speed of scrolling, on android if negative means gesture to the right, if positive means gesture to the left. in ios is the other way around.

```
  const foo = (velocity) => {
    if (Platform.OS == 'ios')
      velocity > 0 ? console.log('to left') : console.log('to right');
    else velocity < 0 ? console.log('to left') : console.log('to right');
  };

  <FlatList
    data={data}
    horizontal
    onScroll={e => foo(e.nativeEvent.velocity?.x)} //or y
  />
```

Comment: `e.nativeEvent.velocity` is undefined